# Is wal_keep_segments required with streaming replication when archive and restore commands are set?

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-12, repmgr

I have a 2 node postresql(12.9) cluster with streaming replication enabled. I have also set the archive and restore commands which I verified is working as expected. No replication slots or wal_keep_segments configured.

```
archive_command ='test ! -f /archive_location/%f && cp %p /archive_location/%f'
restore_command = 'cp /archive_location/%f %p'
```

In this setup, I notice that if the standby disconnects after receiving a partial WAL file and if the same WAL gets archived and recycled from pg_wal on the primary node, then on reconnection, this standby never catches up with primary.

The error seen on standby is - `ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000000000000XX has already been removed.`

Debugging revealed the following -

1- Issue only seen when partial WAL file written on standby at time of disconnection. Since streaming replication is enabled, postgres doesn't wait for the 16MB WAL segment to fill up before shipping WAL to standby. So there could be partially written WAL on standby at any point. Confirmed by file compare of same WAL on primary and standby -

```
cmp 0000000100000000000000XX /tmp/0000000100000000000000XX
0000000100000000000000XX /tmp/0000000100000000000000XX differ: byte 15722105, line 68077
```

On reconnection, postgres first tries restoring WAL from archive but on failure, falls on streaming the same WAL from publisher over TCP connection. Since wal_keep_segments is not set, this WAL is recycled from pg_wal on publisher and standby is now stuck in this loop

```
628ed196.bd8bf 0DEBUG:  00000: switched WAL source from stream to archive after failure
2
628ed196.bd8bf 0DEBUG:  00000: record with incorrect prev-link 1/FDFF2008 at 0/EDEFE678
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776383 628ed196.bd8bf 0LOCATION:  ReadRecord, xlog.c:4348
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776383 628ed196.bd8bf 0DEBUG:  00000: switched WAL source from archive to stream after failure
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776629 628ed19b.bd9b5 0FATAL:  XX000: could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000000000000XX has already been removed
```

Given this info looks like wal_keep_segments is needed even when archive + restore is set for streaming replication. Is this true? Am I missing something?

Edit - Adding necessary log info here for improved readability -

```
628ed196.bd8bf 0DEBUG:  00000: switched WAL source from stream to archive after failure
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776383 628ed196.bd8bf 0LOCATION:  WaitForWALToBecomeAvailable, xlog.c:12208
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776383 628ed196.bd8bf 0DEBUG:  00000: record with incorrect prev-link 1/FDFF2008 at 0/EDEFE678
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776383 628ed196.bd8bf 0LOCATION:  ReadRecord, xlog.c:4348 2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776383 628ed196.bd8bf 0DEBUG:  00000: switched WAL source from archive to stream after failure
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776381 628ed196.bd8bd 0LOCATION:  LogChildExit, postmaster.c:3697
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776629 628ed19b.bd9b5 0LOG:  00000: started streaming WAL from primary at 0/ED000000 on timeline 1
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776629 628ed19b.bd9b5 0LOCATION:  WalReceiverMain, walreceiver.c:372 2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776629 628ed19b.bd9b5 0FATAL:  XX000: could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000000000000ED has already been removed
```

Comment: The current release of 12 is 12.11, which contains a bugfix which *might* be relevant to this.

Comment: Can you reproduce this at will by setting up new master and replica, or is it just a one time occurrence?  Can you go back farther in the log file to see why did it "switched WAL source from stream to archive" in the first place?

Comment: I am able to reproduce this as follows - 1. Have a series of writes on primary and wait for WAL to be shipped to standby. On Standby verify the WAL file(say X) is not filled to 16 MB segment limit and now disconnect standby. 2. Continue writes on publisher till the WAL file X is recycled from pg_wal directory. 3. Reconnect standby. At this point standby errors on restoring WAL file X from archive - error seen - ```incorrect prev-link``` then falls on streaming same WAL file from primary

Comment: From log dump - `628ed196.bd8bf 0DEBUG:  00000: switched WAL source from stream to archive after failure
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776383 628ed196.bd8bf 0LOCATION:  WaitForWALToBecomeAvailable, xlog.c:12208
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776383 628ed196.bd8bf 0DEBUG:  00000: record with incorrect prev-link 1/FDFF2008 at 0/EDEFE678 2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776383 628ed196.bd8bf 0LOCATION:  ReadRecord, xlog.c:4348
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776383 628ed196.bd8bf 0DEBUG:  00000: switched WAL source from archive to stream after failure
`

Comment: `2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776381 628ed196.bd8bd 0LOCATION:  LogChildExit, postmaster.c:3697
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776629 628ed19b.bd9b5 0LOG:  00000: started streaming WAL from primary at 0/ED000000 on timeline 1
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776629 628ed19b.bd9b5 0LOCATION:  WalReceiverMain, walreceiver.c:372
2022-05-26 06:32:19 IST   776629 628ed19b.bd9b5 0FATAL:  XX000: could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000000000000ED has already been removed`

Comment: I think you are just doing something wrong. If it were easy to reproduce the way you describe, i would have seen it hundreds of times long before now.

Comment: Please include log entries by editing your question.  In the comments, they are unreadable.

Comment: I edited original post to add logs from the comments. Let me know what additional info you need from repro setup?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you have `restore_command` defined properly on the standby server, you don't need `wal_keep_segments` (`wal_keep_size` in later versions) on the primary.

If you define `restore_command` on the standby, it will restore the WAL segment from there. You say that the WAL segment *gets archived* and recycled on the primary, so the standby must be able to get it from there.

The standby should try to fetch the WAL segment from archive, even if it already has a partially filled local WAL segment with the same name. I would consider anything else a bug.

Are you sure that `restore_command` is set *on the standby*? Don't you get any messages about "restoring WAL segment from archive"?

Comment: Logs from standby. WAL is getting restored from local archive directory on standby `2022-05-27 17:00:43 IST   3676726 6290b65d.381a36 0LOG:  restored log file "0000000100000016000000A9" from archive`
`2022-05-27 17:00:44 IST   3676726 6290b65d.381a36 0LOG:  restored log file "0000000100000016000000AA" from archive`
`2022-05-27 17:00:44 IST   3676726 6290b65d.381a36 0LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 16/AA8624F0`
`2022-05-27 17:00:44 IST   3676726 6290b65d.381a36 0LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 249 at 16/AA8624F0
`

Comment: `2022-05-27 17:00:44 IST   3676724 6290b65c.381a34 0LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2022-05-27 17:00:44 IST   3676776 6290b664.381a68 0LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 16/AA000000 on timeline 1
2022-05-27 17:00:44 IST   3676776 6290b664.381a68 0FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 0000000100000016000000AA has already been removed
`

Comment: I'm assuming you meant `wal_keep_segments` instead of `wal_keep_size` in your comment, correct me if I'm wrong.  From above logs it looks like restore command is working on standby. But any error restoring a WAL log (incorrect prev-link, invalid resource manager etc) causes it to stream log from primary's pg_wal. Is this not expected?  In your response, you mentioned `WAL segment gets archived and recycled on the primary, so the standby must be able to get it from there.` Does this mean restore command should fetch WAL from primary's archive directory if restore fails ?

Comment: From those logs it looks like the WAL segment got archived, but the restored WAL segment contains an error. So there is either a software bug in PostgreSQL that wrote bad WAL, or the archived WAL segment got messed up somehow, PostgreSQL should *never* archive a partial WAL segment. A partial WAL segment on the standby would be no problem, because it gets overwritten from the archive. Unfortunately it is probably hard to reproduce the problem, but analyzing the broken archived WAL segment would certainly be interesting.

Comment: Thanks. Few more questions - 1. From documentation here -[link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION) - it states - `The standby connects to the primary, which streams WAL records to the standby as they're generated, without waiting for the WAL file to be filled.` So when standby streams a WAL record, is it stored on standby's pg_wal(or archive) directory?   2. My restore command is in postgres.conf instead of postgres.auto.conf. Does that have an impact? 3. Recco on how to move forward to confirm if this is a bug. Posted on postgres slack channel for now.

Comment: 1. Yes, in `pg_wal`. 2. No. 3. I don't know Recco, but the best thing would be if you can reproduce the problem at will.

Comment: Able to repro issue - [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/312589/is-wal-keep-segments-required-with-streaming-replication-when-archive-and-restor#comment608962_312589)

Comment: No. I see no bash command or SQL statement there, just text.

Comment: I don't have a script to push writes. Currently doing it using our product UI by uploading large csv files to primary and bringing network interface down on standby during the upload process. In that case would pg_logs with additional transaction info help?

Comment: Probably not. What would help is a sequence of commands, starting with `initdb`, that reproduces the problem.